# How to import modules in the tree structure using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a `main.py` file which follows a directory structure as below

```
Mypackage
├──src
|  ├──main.py
|  ├──main.spec
|  └──settings.py
└──data
```

The `main.py` is like below

```
import numpy as np
from src.settings import args
```

My `main.spec` file is as below

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['../src'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['../src', '../src/settings.py', '../src/utils.py', '../src/paramtree_v2.py'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=True)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir='.',
          console=True )
```

`pyinstaller` successfully creates a standalone file however when I run the application I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` error. How do I modify the `main.spec` to avoid this error?

One workaround is that in my `main.py` file I just use `from settings import args` however I want to keep the structure in the code as much as possible.

**[EDIT]**

This works after I use `noarchive=False` in the `main.spec` file

Answer (score 0):

since main.py is inside the src, pyinstaller is treating the src folder as the root, so the bundled program contain the files inside src instead of containing the src folder with the files.

move your `main.py` and `main.spec` to the module folder and it should work (remember to also remove all of the `..` inside the spec)

Comment: I get following error when I include this in pathex
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-'

Comment: try to move the main.py to the module folder and see if it works

Comment: looks like this is a known bug https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4034

Comment: I edited the answer, try what I suggested if you're okay with main being in the Module's dir